# The backend version is not supported to design database diagrams or tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ssms

I'm trying to add a table to my newly created database through SQL Server Management Studio.
However I get the error:

> *the backend version is not supported to design database diagrams or tables*

To see my currently installed versions I clicked about in SSMS and this is what came up:

[image]

What's wrong here?

Comment: First Google result ... are you looking at a 2012 database from a 2008 SSMS application? http://calyansql.blogspot.com/2013/08/this-backend-version-is-not-supported.html

Comment: @AHiggins
I've looked at that too. However I don't see any way to update SSMS to 2012

Answer (score 254, accepted):

This is commonly reported as an error due to using the wrong version of SSMS(Sql Server Management Studio). Use the version designed for your database version. You can use the command `select @@version` to check which version of sql server you are actually using. This version is reported in a way that is easier to interpret than that shown in the Help About in SSMS.

---

Using a newer version of SSMS than your database is generally error-free, i.e. backward compatible.

Comment: I ran the query and this is what got returned:
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3000.0

So yea - I see I need to update my SMSS to 2012.
However every time I run the exe offered at:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=29062

I get a message saying no updates are available.
I cannot find any way to update SMSS - even though it sounds insanely dumb.

Comment: Always include the exact error message. You should be able to install SqlExpress 2012 (to get SMSS). You might be able to just do a reconfigure or repair install to make sure SMSS 2012 is running. You also might have 2008 & 2012 and are running SMSS 2008 when you could be using 2012

Comment: I launch the exe file. I click "Upgrade from SQL Server 2005, 2008, or 2008 R2". Then I get the message: "There are no updates for SQL Server found online"

Comment: I think this is supposed to be an informative message, you should be able to continue with the install IIRC

Comment: Ahh finally I got the 2008 version removed and yes you were right - the 2012 version was already installed. Works now - thanks!

Comment: Also, if you let Visual Studio create the database for you with Code First then that can cause the error also when using SSMS.

Comment: I got this error when the sql server was of version Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2000.8 (X64) and I used ssms 2012 version 11.0.2100.60. I only get the error when right clicking a table and then click "Design". So to see which columns the table has, I have to expand the +, which works. Is my ssms confused in some way?

Comment: Just install multiple version of SQL server management studio. Sometimes you'll run into a situation where some of your DB's are installed with SQL Server 14, 12, 11 etc. So instead of upgrading your only install of management studio, have multiple installed.

Comment: Yep I had some how loaded a second older version of sql management studio ... Probably should uninstall that.

Comment: It would be nice if v18 had knowledge of the new major version as it says no update is available. Hopefully the updater in v19 will be more future forward.

Answer (score 24):

I found the solution. The SSMS version was older. I uninstalled SSMS from the server, went to the microsoft website and downloaded a more current version and now the Database Diagrams works ok.

[image]

Comment: That's odd hat new version of SQL server is released, but SSMS still in preview.

Comment: Mmm strange that the latest stable version includes version 15 for some reason. @Chinthaka Sandaruwan's answer for using the version 19 preview instead of version 18 fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 11):

if you got this error in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) 18.12.1 in 2022, please download Download SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) 19 (Preview) and install it, a link is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms-19?view=sql-server-ver16), download the latest one, this provided link is the current latest version.

Comment: It seems to be a bug in the latest stable release. Yes, installing the preview fixes it.

Answer (score 8):

Just a heads up, Got the same message when I installed SQL Express 2022... Literally Installed SSMS (v18) by clicking the link after Express finished installing. I deleted V18 and downloaded V19, which is still in beta, and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 7):

I ran into this problem when SQL Server 2014 standard was installed on a server where SQL Server Express was also installed.  I had opened SSMS from a desktop shortcut, not realizing right away that it was SSMS for SQL Server Express, not for 2014. SSMS for Express returned the error, but SQL Server 2014 did not.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, although I solved out by creating the table using a script query instead of doing it graphically. See the snipped below:

```
USE [Database_Name]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_Name](
[tableID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[column_2] [datatype] NOT NULL,
[column_3] [datatype] NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT [PK_Table_Name] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[tableID] ASC
)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using other design tools like Visual Studio. You can connect to your DB from Visual Studio and use VS design tools which is very easier and faster than writing T-Sql commands.

Answer (score 0):

So, when attempting to add a diagram to my LocalDB `Microsoft SQL Server 2022 (RTM) - 16.0.1000.6 (X64)   Oct  8 2022 05:58:25   Copyright (C) 2022 Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 10.0 <X64> (Build 22000: ) (Hypervisor)` I had to upgrade SSMS to this:

[image]

By the way, I know `@@version` says I am running Windows 10, but I am not. Not sure if that is important to you or not.

[image]

Answer (score -10):

You only get that message if you try to use Designer or diagrams. If you use t-SQL it works fine:

```
Select * 

into newdb.dbo.newtable
from olddb.dbo.yourtable
```

where `olddb.dbo.yourtable` has been created in 2008 exactly as you want the table to be in 2012