# Database Design and relation diagrams details

Tags: sql-server, database, schema

We have a production SQL Server and my desktop has SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio software installed. I have recently been given a task to perform data mining on our server DBs.

We have around 100 or more of tables there and it is getting very difficult for me to see how tables are related or has been created.

For a particular scenario I have cornered to 3 tables amongst the 100's that we have - but I cannot formulate how these tables are related with each other. I mean if only I know that one's table column is PK / FK of other then only I can execute something like below to extract data's -

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablea,tableb 
WHERE tableb.id = tablea.id
```

and do data mining on the result data set.

Please let me know how can I get all the tables and it relation details? What tool I can use such that further on information like above can be extracted or database designs can be known?

I tried to create the DB diagram but it showed me below error:

[image]

Do I need to install any other tool?

Below is my MS SQL Studio version details:

[image]

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your solution is to use a database diagram (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189078.aspx)

Just drag all tables on the screen and it will show you the relations, this of course only when the primary-keys/foreign-keys are there.

For the error you are getting:
if I google that for you I get:
[The backend version is not supported to design database diagrams or tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25146474/the-backend-version-is-not-supported-to-design-database-diagrams-or-tables)

The answer marked as the solution is:

> This is commonly reported as an error due to using the wrong version
>   of SMSS. Use the version designed for your database version. You can
>   use select @@version to check which version of sql server you are
>   actually using

Comment: Thanks I tried the method but get an error - I have updated my question also. Please let me know how to resolve the same

Comment: I am sorry - I have just started to learn MS SQL Studio - where can we set the SMSS and where do we select @@version

Comment: What do you see when you run the following query?: select @@version 
In my case it says: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1)

Comment: It states - Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.5058.0 (X64)   May 14 2014 18:34:29   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

Comment: And what verison of Microsoft SQL server management studio are you using?

Comment: I don't understand, @@version tells you it is version 2012, but the screenshot states 2008R2 Are you connecting to this 2008R2 database or to the new 2012 database?

Comment: Ok got it I need Sql Server Management Studio version 2012 - thanks a lot