# Accessing tables in a visual format in SQL Server 2014 Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have Microsoft SQL server 2016 installed as well as SQL Server 2014 Management Studio.

On trying to create a new database diagram, or on trying to create a table from the design view (instead of create statements), I get an error saying:

> This backend version is not supported to design database diagrams or
>   tables. (MS Visual Database Tools)

However, i can create tables and insert data by using statements.

One of the SO answers [for a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25146474/the-backend-version-is-not-supported-to-design-database-diagrams-or-tables)  advised the following:

> This is commonly reported as an error due to using the wrong version
>   of SMSS. Use the version designed for your database version.

What version of SSMS corresponds to SQL server 2016? Or is this issue not related to compatibility?

Comment: I'm Using Sql server 2016 version 13 And Able to Create Table From Design View Can you Provide Screen Shot Of your Error

Comment: Sure. This happened when i tried to create a database diagram: http://imageshack.com/a/img922/5656/9rJCc6.png

Comment: Ugh using the design view is not a great way to create a table. Just learn the statements and write. Once you get used to it you will that it is much faster to write the code instead of grabbing the mouse.

Comment: You stated you are using 2016 and 2014. Which version of SSMS are you using and what database version?

Comment: @SeanLange Learning the statements is definitely useful, but the design view does seem convenient at times. Also, this is possibly just one of the missing features. Might as well fix it before i've created more databases.

Comment: @SeanLange SSMS: 2014. SQL Server (database): 2016

Comment: you won't allow to create Database Diagram in Design Mode But Table you Can Create Check once again right click on Table  which will open a new window there you can easily create the Table

Comment: Well....as you have noticed the version doesn't match hence the error. Starting with 2016 the way SSMS is installed has changed. It is now a separate application entirely. Search for SSMS 2016 and you will find the download links at the top.

Comment: @AlfaizAhmed Right clicked on the Tables folder and then the Table option, but i'm getting the same error.

Comment: @SeanLange Guess i'll have to do that. Any idea if SSMS 2017 is compatible with SQL Server 2016?

Comment: Go read about how SSMS works now. It is very different and will no longer be so version specific.

Comment: @rahulSaha SSMS 2017 is compatible with Sql Server 2016

Comment: Thanks! SSMS 2017 does allow for database diagrams and table design views.