# SSMS version vs SSDT version - This backend version is not supported to design database diagrams or tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I ****right-click a table and select **Design**, I receive the error
As seen in the attached screenshot.

[image: SQL Server results]

It seems that the version differs between 'select @@version'(SQl server 2016 SP1 -**13.0.4001.0** and what it displayed when selecting Help/About - version **11.0.5388**

I have tried updating SSMS, Updating Visual Studio 2017 and SSDT and nothing seems to fix the issue. If anyone know how to get the versions in sync, it would certainly save me a lot more frustration. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The backend version is not supported to design database diagrams or tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25146474/the-backend-version-is-not-supported-to-design-database-diagrams-or-tables)

Comment: The reason is that SSMS 2012 (the client tool) can't edit SQL Server 2016 database diagrams, because SQL 2016 uses new features. You can download a newer SMSS version for free.

Comment: Hi Peter, Thank you for your answer, however, downloaded the latest SSMS(Version 17.6) and ran the install. This did not change SSMS. I even rebooted my computer and About still displays (11.0.5388) . Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Installing a new SSMS does not upgrade or uninstall the old version, they install next to each other. Try if you can uninstall the old version through Control Panel. Then look through your Start menu for the new one, it's probably named 'Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio'.

Comment: Bingo. Thank you very much. Even though the new version had been installed, I was clicking the old(Most Used) icon. Lower down was the 'New' version and that works fine.  Thank you again