# the backend version is not supported to design database diagrams

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms-2014, ssms-2016

When i wanna create new table in ssms 2016 or ssms 2014 give me an error

> The backend version is not supported to design database diagrams

Version is

> Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM) - 14.0.1000.169 (X64)   Aug 22 2017 17:04:49   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 10.0  (Build 14393: )

There is one point here

I connect to another server from my local computer

Comment: "seems pretty clear" I cant understand where is the problem

Comment: what is the version of SSMS you are using ? Get the latest and try

Comment: You using a modern SSMS connected to a prehistoric version of sql server by any chance? (Or vice versa, an old SSMS against a modern SQLS?

Comment: Version of SSMS is 2016

Comment: So it's SSMS 2016 with SQLS 2017? Do you see the same error if you use SSMS 2017?

Comment: I use SSMS 2017 and its work as expected thnx

Comment: I am using the latest version of SQL Server: Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-GDR) (KB4517790) - 15.0.2070.41 (X64)   Oct 28 2019 19:56:59   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 10.0 <X64> (Build 18362: ) (Hypervisor) and SSMS V 18.4. I still get the same message.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The backend version is not supported to design database diagrams or tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25146474/the-backend-version-is-not-supported-to-design-database-diagrams-or-tables)