# Error adding a table in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Simply I right click on tables and choose table option.

[image: Image Attached]

What is the problem here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The backend version is not supported to design database diagrams or tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25146474/the-backend-version-is-not-supported-to-design-database-diagrams-or-tables)

Comment: Try to search for the error message first, and if you found no solution (or you couldn't implement it somehow), then post a question.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are trying to add a table to a system database and not one of your own databases. Make sure you have the correct database selected first.

For instance, click the `+` next to the `school` database, then select the tables folder within that and try to create a table. That should work

Comment: It doesn't work. I tried to create table in school database but same notification came

Comment: It's in my computer

Comment: What version is you SQL server management studio, and what version is your database? It may be that you need to update SSMS.

Comment: Maybe. I think so

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using latest version of SQL Server (Version 15) Express.

For that, you need to install latest version of SSMS. You can download the same from the below path: [Install Standalone SSMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15)

Otherwise, you might face incompatibility issues between SSMS and SQL Server version.

Answer (score -1):

Using a newer version of SSMS than your database is generally error-free, i.e. backward compatible.You can use the command select @@version to check which version of sql server you are actually using.