# how do I change Microsoft Sql Server Studio 2022 from rtm?

Tags: ssms

I recently downloaded ssms 2022 but it refuses to accept connections, make diagrams, giving comments, relations, give design view of the table, etc. the software is upto date and it keeps giving errors like the back end doesn't support. How do i go about this, have tried using both express and developer edition and face the same problem. it says both versions are rtm.
a solution on how to make my ssms function effectively.

Comment: There is no `ssms 2022`. SSMS hasn't been versioned with years (or SQL Server versions) for several years. The latest version is `18.12.1`

Answer (score 0):

The SSMS version being older than the database version. you have to download SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) 19 (Preview)
[Download SSMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms-19?view=sql-server-ver16). It is now available and is the recommended version of SSMS for SQL Server 2022.

you could back to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25146474/the-backend-version-is-not-supported-to-design-database-diagrams-or-tables) for more information.